# "exhaust gas aftertreatment" vs. "exhaust gas after treatment"

Tags: orthography

My question is related to filters and catalysts in vehicles.

I would name them "exhaust gas aftertreatment". However MS Word always corrects this to  "exhaust gas after treatment".

What is correct?

Comment: What is the phrase *exhaust gas aftertreatment* actually describing?

Comment: The devices (catalysts, filters) which are used for purifying the exhaust gas from combustion engines. I technical discussions this phrase is quite common. Also native speakers use it. However, I have seen both kinds of spelling, so I don't know which is correct.

Comment: But what is "aftertreatment"? After what? It's not an English word (which is why Word is correcting it to something which is English words), so you need to describe it in as much detail as possible.

Comment: @BerndGit: Thank you. Then it's the noun form, stressed on _After_, with no space. With a space it's a prepositional phrase, with stress on _treatment_, and the whole noun phrase refers to the gas, not the devices or the services they provide. Remember to pronounce them that way: /'æftərtritmənt/. The first /t/ in /trit/ is aspirated, and may be affricated in American English: [tʰʃrit].

Comment: MS Word makes *suggestions*.  And often pretty stupid ones.

Comment: "Aftertreatment" is a perfectly legitimate "coinage" to describe, say, a catalytic converter on an gasoline engine.  Some would argue it should be "after-treatment", but I wouldn't, since "after" is perfectly legitimate prefix and, as such, requires no special handling when used with a standard noun.

Comment: Why wouldn't it just be _exhaust gas treatment_? Unless it's something you do after the gas has been through the EGR and cat and then I guess it'd be the same _after-_ as in after-cooler, after-burner, and after-treatment. OED has _after-treatment_ as _Later or subsequent treatment_.

Comment: @Frank: In automotive industry the word 'aftertreatment' is more much mur common than just calling it 'treatment'

Comment: @John Lawler: This is inline with my Intuition.   Thinking about it more I now wander why we have blanks at "exhaust gas" (no doubt here. I've only seen it this way) and not "exhaustgas" or "exhaust-gas".

Comment: Blanks are a new invention, and different languages use them different ways. And hyphens just complicate matters, usually unsuccessfully. English spelling and punctuation is something one must endure philosophically, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hyphen to link those words.

"Exhaust gas after treatment" sounds like an instruction to vent gas upon completion of treatment.

I think that 'exhaust gas after-treatment' conveys the the idea you're trying to convey without having to create a whole new word; MS word should allow it too.

Edit: I do agree with the notion put forward in HotLicks' comment. He's suggested that aftertreatment is a reasonable coinage and pointed out that MS word offers suggestions rather than absolute truths.

Comment: There's no need for new coinage - after-treatment is in the OED and has been in hyphenated form since 1910.

Comment: @Frank Of course there is no need, that's why I didn't change the body of my answer. What I did do was agree that it would not be unreasonable.